# How do I enable Silent Mode?

Tags: ring-fit-adventure

In Ring Fit Adventure, during the tutorial the narrator mentions a Silent Mode that can be enabled that essentially removes the running requirement. I decided to go with the Standard Mode initially, but this was a mistake with how fast they get you running. However, now that I enabled it, I can't seem to find a way to disable it or select the other option.

So, how do you enable Silent Mode in Ring Fit Adventure after a mode has been selected during setup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an option in the **Settings**, although it's a bit hidden:

- Go back to the main menu where you can pick your game mode.
- **Open Adventure** (might work in the other modes, too—didn't try).
- **Pick your Profile** (this is profile specific after all).
- Press the **left action button** on your Ring-Con (i.e. **B**).
- Wait for the menu to open.
- On the bottom left you'll find a section **Settings**.
- In this sub-menu you can change everything once again, including the run mode, if you move down a bit. *(Note that changing the run-mode will force a re-calibration for obvious reasons.)*

Here's the whole process in a short clip, note that my system is set to German, but the location of the elements etc. is identical for all languages:

Comment: Well this is awkward... I never waited long enough for that menu to load and always closed it before it finished. I figured it was some sort of weird 8 ball thing...

Thanks!